# How is the quadratic equation formed?

Tags: quadratics, recreational-mathematics

Recently I was going through a problem. Below is the problem.

Each evening after the dinner the SIS's students gather together to play the game of Sport Mafia.For the tournament, Alya puts candies into the box, which will serve as a prize for a winner.

To do that, she performs n actions. The first action performed is to put a single candy into the box. For each of the remaining moves she can choose from two options:

> the first option, in case the box contains at least one candy, is to take exactly one candy out and eat it. This way the number of candies in the box decreased by 1
>
> the second option is to put candies in the box. In this case, Alya will put 1 more candy, than she put in the previous time.

Thus, if the box is empty, then it can only use the second option. For example, one possible sequence of Alya's actions look as follows:

```
put one candy into the box;
put two candies into the box;
eat one candy from the box;
eat one candy from the box;
put three candies into the box;
eat one candy from the box;
put four candies into the box;
eat one candy from the box;
put five candies into the box;
```

This way she will perform 9 actions, the number of candies at the end will be 11, while Alya will eat 4 candies in total.

Given the total number of actions n and the number of candies at the end k, You need to find the total number of sweets Alya ate. That is the number of moves of the first option. It's guaranteed, that for the given n and k, the answer always exists.

Now the quadratic equation I found from a solution is

**$x^2+3x-(2k+2n)=0$**

How is it formed???

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $x$ is the number of sweets eaten and $n$ is the total number of actions, then $n-x$ is the number of times she put in sweets.  That means she put in

$$1+2+3+ \cdots +(n-x)$$

sweets.  The formula for adding up the first $n-x$ integers is

$$1+2+3+ \cdots +(n-x) = \frac{(n-x)(n-x+1)}{2}.$$

So that's the total number of candies she put in.  Since there are $k$ sweets left in the box and $x$
sweets eaten, you must have

$$k+x = \frac{(n-x)(n-x+1)}{2}.$$

Comment: its perfect!!. Thanks

Comment: This equation doesn't seem to match the given solution.  There's no $n^2$ term in the given solution...

Comment: @MichaelBurr  Yeah, he's got some typos in there.  Notice that his example with $n=9$ and $k=11$ doesn't give the correct value for $x$ in his version of the formula.